# Advantages of Integer.parseInt() over Integer constructor

Tags: java

We can directly do the following conversion:

```
String s="123";
int a=new Integer(s);
```

Then what are the advantages to using `Integer.parseInt()` method?

Comment: `.parseInt()` allows you to specify a *radix* - the `Integer` constructors do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer constructor internally calls `parseInt`, which returns `int`. If you call the `parseInt` directly you avoid autoboxing (constructor returns `Integer`).

```
public Integer(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    this.value = parseInt(s, 10);
}
```

Also using `parseInt` you can parse the String using different radix than 10. For instance:

```
int hex = Integer.parseInt("FF", 16); // 255
int bin = Integer.parseInt("10", 2); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you do (implicitly) one additional boxing operation (to an `Integer` object) which you avoid when using `Integer.parseInt`. `Integer.parseInt` just directly gives you an `int` from your input `String`.

Basically your code is equivalent to:

```
String s = "123";
int a = (new Integer(s)).intValue();
```

As you see, you actually don't need that `new Integer(s)` object,
all you need is the primitive `int` value stored it in.